# How to center vertically a container div

Tags: jquery, css, html, center, vertical-alignment

I can't center vertically `popup_interstitial_table` that contains an ads type container.

The fiddle it is autoexplained: http://jsfiddle.net/NomikOS/D8LLM/

> jQuery solutions are welcome too.

HTML:

```
<div id="popup_interstitial">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="popup_interstitial_pro_head_text">
            Headline text 
        </div>
        <div id="child">
            <div id="popup_interstitial_table">
                <div id="popup_interstitial_row2">
                    <div id="popup_interstitial_title"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
                    <img id="popup_interstitial_image" src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
                    <div id="popup_interstitial_description"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The related CSS code is:

```
#popup_interstitial_pro_head_text{
    color:#FFF; 
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 0.05em 0.05em #666;
    background-color: #A5CF4C;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-top: 0.8%;
    padding-bottom: 0.8%;
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #648323;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #759928;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #333333;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #333333;
    khtml-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #333333;
    filter: shadow(color=#333333, direction=135, strength=0);
}
#popup_interstitial {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#111;
    z-index:9999;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#popup_interstitial_table {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background-color:#E7E7E7;
    padding: 1em 2.2em;
    font: 0.85em "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 5%;
    vertical-align: center;

}
#popup_interstitial_title{
    color:#FFF; 
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 0 0 0.3em;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #777;
    background-color: #888; 
    border-radius: 0.3em;
}
#popup_interstitial_description{
    padding-top: 1.7em;
    padding-bottom: 1.2em;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #ccc;
    line-height:1.5em;
}

#popup_interstitial_image{
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin: 25px 20px 3px 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #333333;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #333333;
    khtml-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #333333;
    filter: shadow(color=#333333, direction=135, strength=0);
    padding: 4px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    float: left;
}
```

This is the most important:

```
#parent {position: relative;}
#child {
    padding: 0% 0;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish: that works if you want to center horizontally.

Comment: @JFK - You are right, of course; I mixed up the two.

Comment: One of these: http://reisio.com/examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your current structure, you have two solutions to make it work:

## 1) CSS

Wrap the elements with a div and use this trick:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/D8LLM/9/) Example! <sup>(If you move the frame up and down, you see that the target stays vertically centered.)</sup>

```
#childWrap {                  // the new element, the mentioned wrapper
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#child {                      // your element that needs to be restyled
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#popup_interstitial_table {   // the element vertically aligned
  width: 50%;
  margin: -48px auto 0 auto;
}
```

What is done here is to set the wrapper element to display as a table, occupying the entire width and height of its parent (`#parent`).

Then, we can set the `#child` to display as a table-cell, and set its contents to vertical align at the middle.

Now the trick, since the `#parent` also contains another element that you need to stay put, but have its height removed from the "center" calculations for the `#popup_interstitial_table`, we need to pull the `#popup_interstitial_table` with a `margin-top:-60px` to fix its position. The negative margin is the height that the `#popup_interstitial_pro_head_text` occupies.

### Important note:

Since you have this structure, in order to pass to the browser the fix, your `#popup_interstitial_pro_head_text` needs to work with a single unit, I've chosen `px` for the example.

You had a mixture of `%` and `em` on several declarations!

---

**On a side note:**

> <s>Vertical-align: center;</s>

**You use:**

> vertical-align: middle;

See [this link](http://w3.org/tr/css21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) for further information!

---

## 2) JQUERY

With jQuery, you can collect the space being occupied by the `#popup_interstitial_table` and calculate the necessary top and left fix values to keep it vertically centered:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/sU3LZ/) Example! <sup>(If you move the frame up and down, you see that the target stays vertically centered.)</sup>

**JQUERY**

```
function center() {
  var $target = $('#popup_interstitial_table'),
      $header = $('#popup_interstitial_pro_head_text'),
      fixTop  = ($target.outerHeight(true)/2)-($header.outerHeight(true)/2),
      fixLeft = $target.outerWidth(true)/2;

  $target.css({
    "margin-top": "-" + fixTop + "px",
    "margin-left" : "-" + fixLeft + "px"
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  center();
});
```

**CSS**

To prevent massive script calculations, the CSS should get fixed to this:

```
#parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;        // this was added
}
#child {
  padding: 0% 0;
  height: 100%;        // this was added
}
#popup_interstitial_table {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  background-color:#E7E7E7;
  padding: 1em 2.2em;
  font: 0.85em "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;  // this was added
  top: 50%;            // this was added
  left: 50%;           // this was added
}
```

So, a repeat that without changing your current structure, this are the two solutions I could think of to center your element!

Comment: @reisio, Tks, link updated on the answer! (way to sleepy last night)

Comment: +1 Your `1) CSS` solution works as expected and thanks for the other tips!

Comment: @NomikOS, had to sweat a bit to make it work under your structure ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use this CSS:

```
#child {
    display: table
}
#popup_interstitial_table {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center
}
```

And add your other CSS to it.

See [Example of vertical centering](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center-example)

and
[CSS: centering things](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html).

Comment: It's a good choice if cross-browser compatibility is not a must. As far as I know, there are still a lot of IE browsers out there and most don't support `display: table-cell`. "Centering things" doesn't play well in IE7/8

Comment: @JFK - Using [IE NetRenderer](http://netrenderer.com), IE8 displays it fine, but IE7, 6 etc. don't.

Comment: I use this across the board with the help of modernizr

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any good way to centre an element vertically without using table cells.  In that case, it is rather straightforward, but you go back to table-based layout, which I guess you're trying to avoid.

Question in reply:  How important is it for the element to be vertically centred?

Another option is to use javascript to set margins at render-time.

Comment: +1: I was about to suggest a jQuery method to overcome this css limitation (unless you use tables), but the last time I did it I got down voted because it wasn't a css solution.

Comment: I've seen some approaches that finagle `%` margins/padding, but at the moment I haven't been able to replicate.

Comment: @jfk I have edited the question to accept jquery solutions. Please shoot.-

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can achive your result through two easy steps:-

just define **display:table-cell** & **vertical-align:middle** to your this id **#popup_interstitial_table**

```
#popup_interstitial_table {
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    display: table-cell;
    font: 0.85em "Trebuchet MS",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 5% auto 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 450px;
}
```

see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/D8LLM/34/

Comment: that was already proposed by Shaquin Trifonoff and it works if cross-browser compatibility is not a must.

Comment: @JFK is my answer is wrong because if you down-voting someone so you should mention like your answer is wrong so i am down-voting you and for cross-browser compatibility issue you are down-voting i think this not good i am just telling you the exact things and  i think my answer is right and its working fine on safari, chrome & Firefox....

Comment: @JFK I guess you didn't check my answer properly if you will see my answer properly and compare with Shaquin Trifonoff answer so you will get it how i gave the answer first thing there is no need to define display:table parent so Shaquin has given in his answer so just compare the both answer's and check properly than you will get the difference......

Comment: @ShailenderArora i have seen your answer and compare with above one its totally different.......how people are saying this is duplicate answers...i am just wondering about it...